# What should the poker.stackexchange.com logo and site design look ike?

Tags: discussion, design

It would be good to get the (inevitably long running) discussion started on this one, as everyone is likely to want to contribute something to this.

I'll refer you to the [7 Essential Meta Questions of Every Beta](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/) article for an idea of what this relates to. Numbers 4 and 5, to my mind, come under the purview of the design elements related to the question.

Go for it...

Answer (score 2):

I think that imagery having to do with traditional green table felt would be great.  I think that a full-on table background would be too gaudy, but it might be possible to do something that suggests felt for the main column, with a rail for the edges.

As far as logos... hmm.  The O in poker could be a chip, or the spine of the P could be a stack of chips.  Just please no dice chips.  I think a stack of red chips as the spine would actually look really cool.

We are also a site on the Stack Exchange network, and both the Stack Exchange and Stack Overflow logos are suggestive of stacks... We could work them into a poker theme fairly easily (chips or cards are both stacked in poker).  I think we need to figure out what the "brand" of the site can be.  Something better than Poker / poker.stackexchange.com.  Again, playing off the stack brand could help, though I think we should avoid Stack Poker type names, since we wouldn't want to be confused with Stock Poker.

Comment: I like the idea of a red stack of chips as the spine of the P. The O as a chip seems overdone and cheezy.

Comment: Changing the logo @Toby has below into a stack of chips would be cool. I'm for getting rid of the grid paper look of the site with something more 'felt-esqe'...

Answer (score 0):

I had the idea of taking the basic stackexchange logo...

[image: SE Icon]

and "cookie-cutting" it in such a way to represent a suit, i.e A spade (♠), a club (♣), a heart (♥), or a diamond (⋄). I will break out the image editor and post a pic here eventually.